# For each guest with at least one booking, list the guest number and how many bookings they have made

Tags: sql

A question in my intro database homework asks:

*"6. For each guest who has made at least one booking, list the guest number and the total number of bookings the guest has made, sorted by guest number."*

The tables I have are:

```
create table Guest (
Guest_No    char(6),
Guest_Name  char(30)    not null,
Address     char(40),
constraint Guest_PK
    primary key (Guest_No)
);

create table Booking (
Hotel_No    char(3),
Guest_No    char(6)     not null,
Date_From   date,
Date_To     date        not null,
Room_No     char(4),
constraint Booking_PK
    primary key (Hotel_No, Room_No, Date_From),
constraint Booking_Guest_FK
    foreign key (Guest_No) references Guest
);
```

The problem I am having is how I am supposed to keep count of how many bookings exist for each guest.

I have tried selecting Guest_No and count of bookings but after that I am unsure as to where to go.

Comment: Besides of the answers, look into aggregation functions, and also check "in" and "exists" operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a grouping exercise.

```
SELECT Guest_No, COUNT(*) 
FROM Booking
GROUP BY Guest_No
ORDER BY Guest_No
```

The `GROUP BY` clause ensures that you'll return a result set with one row per `Guest_No` value; the `COUNT(*)` counts the number of rows that 'match' that `Guest_No`.

You don't need to join because constraint `Booking_Guest_FK` ensures that only valid guests exist in the booking table.

Comment: Great additional explanations, and point on the foreign key which fulfills the requirement: "each guest who has made at least one booking"

Comment: `You don't need to join...` I guess it is pointed to my answer. The reason I put JOIN was to show how to get all guests (yes I know OP wanted only those who has made at least 1 booking). Anyway even with JOIN query optimizer could do [`join elimination`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/glossary.htm#GUID-420638C3-79BE-4ED0-955F-B7EF70685DBC) so there shouldn't be  performance penalty.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `JOIN` and aggregation:

```
SELECT g.GuestNo, COUNT(b.GuestNo) AS cnt
FROM Guest g
JOIN Booking b               --use LEFT JOIN to get all guests even without
  ON g.GuestNo = b.GuestNo   --any booking
GROUP BY g.GuestNo
ORDER BY g.GuestNo ASC;
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name When LEFT JOIN is used then yes, you are right. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Really easy - just use group by

```
select guest_no, count(guest_no) 
from booking 
group by guest_no
order by guest_no;
```

I don't see why we need a join to the other table unless you want to be fancy.